# How to checkbox unchecked without action followed by checking?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I want to ask how to unchceck checkbox without action followed by checking checkbox**(i.e. w/o triggering the `onCheckChangedListener()`)**? 
I have oncheck action, but i want to disable this action for unchecking. Is it possible ?

Here is my code:

```
 chb_czy_zamowic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(context);
                    d1.setContentView(R.layout.ilosc);
                    d1.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                    d1.setTitle("Wybierz ilość");

                    final EditText et_Ilosc;
                    Button b_Ok;
                    Button b_Odejmij;
                    Button b_Dodaj;

                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {

                        et_Ilosc = (EditText) d1
                                .findViewById(R.id.et_Ilosc);

                        et_Ilosc.setText(String.valueOf(i));



                        b_Dodaj = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.b_Dodaj);
                        b_Dodaj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String zmienna_pom = et_Ilosc.getText()
                                        .toString();
                                i = Integer.valueOf(zmienna_pom);
                                setI(i);
                                int k = getI();
                                k++;

                                setI(k);
                                et_Ilosc.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                            }
                        });
                        b_Odejmij = (Button) d1
                                .findViewById(R.id.b_Odejmij);
                        b_Odejmij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String zmienna_pom = et_Ilosc.getText()
                                        .toString();
                                i = Integer.valueOf(zmienna_pom);
                                setI(i);
                                i--;
                                setI(i);
                                et_Ilosc.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                            }
                        });
                        b_Ok = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.b_Ok);
                        b_Ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String zmiennna_pom = et_Ilosc.getText()
                                        .toString();
                                int k = Integer.valueOf(zmiennna_pom);

                                if (k<=0 || k>=100) {

                                                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                            "Niepoprawna wartość" ,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    t.show();
                                    view.chb_czy_zamowic.setChecked(false);
                                    d1.cancel();
                                }
                                else if( et_Ilosc.getText().toString().equals(""))
                                {
                                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                            "Uzupełnij pole ilość" ,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    t.show();
                                    view.chb_czy_zamowic.setChecked(false);
                                    d1.cancel();
                                }
                                else
                                    view.chb_czy_zamowic.setEnabled(false);
                                    view.chb_czy_zamowic.setChecked(false); 


                                    items.get(position).Tow_ilosc -= k;
                                    Towar checkedObject = new Towar();
                                    checkedObject.Tow_ilosc = k;
                                    checkedObject.Kat_id = items
                                            .get(position).Kat_id;
                                    checkedObject.kategoria = items
                                            .get(position).kategoria;
                                    checkedObject.Tow_cena = items
                                            .get(position).Tow_cena;
                                    checkedObject.Tow_id = items
                                            .get(position).Tow_id;
                                    checkedObject.Tow_nazwa = items
                                            .get(position).Tow_nazwa;
                                    MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow
                                            .add(checkedObject);
                                    k = 0;
                                    setI(0);
                                    // et_Ilosc.setText("");
                                    if (MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow
                                            .size() > 0) {
                                        b_zatwierdz
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione = new ArrayList<Towar>(MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow);

                                        Collections
                                                .copy(TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione,
                                                        MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow);

                                    } else {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                                                getContext(),
                                                "Proszę wybrać ilość",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        t.show();
                                    }



                                d1.dismiss();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    ;
                    d1.show();

                }

            });
```

Comment: @Poldie  nothing has changed after adding on .setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: @Piyush Gupta nothing has changed after adding on .setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: @SMR  nothing has changed after adding on .setOnCheckedChangeListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a property, setClickable associated with views which I believe can be used. In the onCheckedChangeListener, see when it gets unchecked and then set this to false. Hope this does the trick for you.

Comment: Lemme know even if it doesn't.

Comment: after adding view.chb_czy_zamowic.setChecked(false); I've got two action one for my checkbox checked and second (i don't know where it is from) caused by unchecking

Comment: use the boolean parameter isChecked for this purpose in the setOnCheckedChangeListener method.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate if you wish on what you want to achieve in your setOnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: How to validate if it was user clicked? where i can get this data from ?

Comment: what do we mean here by user clicked? The CheckBox will be unchecked in the beginning ryt?

Comment: ,sorry i was meaning user checked. Yes after start checkbox is unchacked.

Comment: okay, nice. So now when the user checks it (clicks or touches it), it will become checked and will call the setOnCheckedChange() listener's onCheckedChange() method. Here, you will get the buttonview which is your checkbox and a true or false status (isChecked) for it which will be true in this case. Simply write if(isChecked){ yourButtonView.setClickable(false);} this will make your checkbox non clickable. You will need to customize or modify this as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Define some boolean field that you could set to true when your are tweaking the check states manually and false when you are not and expecting the user input instead. Now the listener can check the value of this field and ignore "software triggered checks" when the flag is true. The optimal location of the flag (method field, static field, etc) depends on the overall program design.

Be sure your code always sets this flag back to false when you finish tweaking the check boxes manually, so not to stay in the permanently locked state. This is one of the cases when `finally` statement may be appropriate.

If you only check the boxes programmatically on initialization, such cluttering may be avoided by setting the listeners only after the states are set.

Comment: Or maybe I could rewrite some code and make condition that totally disable field. What are you think about it ?

Comment: How to validate if it was user clicked? where i can get this data from ?  is this some sort of variable or anything else ?

Comment: Do you have the control on the code that changes the states programmatically or not? If you have, who prevents to set the flag to true at the start of modification and back to false after you are done? If (then I misunderstand) the user clicks on the checkbox and you do not want to have the on change listener fired - what is the purpose of such event listener, then?